# Is powering a 12v DC motor with 11.1 volts a bad idea? (3 * 18560 battaries)

Tags: arduino, power-supply, voltage, dc-motor, lithium-ion

I am working on an Arduino project where I will be controlling 4 individual 12 volt, 0.71 Nominal amp draw DC motors, the arduino will be separately powered with another power supply.

I'm going to use a L298N controller which is known for having a significant voltage drop of 2 volts, so perhaps it's okay to use 4 18560 batteries for the power supply and using only 11.1 bad for the motors?

Comment: How are you getting 11.1 volts? If the controller always drops the supply by 2 volts, I'm seeing 4 li-ion batteries as providing 10.14.8 volts, depending on charge level.

Comment: 18560 batteries are 3.7 volts per unit so 4 would be 14.8 and 3 would be 11.1.

Comment: @RamiRaghfan Are they always at 3.7 V at all different state of charge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever voltage below 12 volts is applied will result in a proportional reduction below the nominal speed at 12 volts. That should cause no problem for the motors.